# Angular library module inject service with abstract class

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created an Angular Component Library, which I distribute via NPM (over Nexus) to several similar projects. This contains a `PageComponent`, which in turn contains a `FooterComponent` and a `NavbarComponent`. In  `NavbarComponent` exists a button, which triggers a `logout` function. This function is to be provided via a `PageService` of the respective project. For this purpose I created an `AbstractPageService` in the Angular Component library (`PageService` extends `AbstractPageService`).

At first I solved this via the `EventEmitter`. But since I had to provide a `logout` function for each new page, I wanted to solve this via one service per project. I pass the `PageService` (Project) with using the `forRoot()` method of Angular Component Library.

Everything works as desired, but wanted to know if there is a better solution or if the solution is so recommendable at all?

I have the following solution for this:

**Components Lib - components.module.ts**

```
import {ModuleWithProviders, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {FontAwesomeModule} from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';


import {NavbarComponent} from './layout/navbar/navbar.component';
import {PageComponent} from './layout/page/page.component';
import {PageHeaderComponent} from './components/page-header/page-header.component';
// ... others ...

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,
    FontAwesomeModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    NavbarComponent,
    PageComponent,
    // ... others ...
  ],
  exports: [
    NavbarComponent,
    PageComponent,
    // ... others ...
  ]
})
export class ComponentsModule {
  static forRoot(pageService): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: ComponentsModule,
      providers: [
        {provide: 'PageService', useClass: pageService}
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

**Component Lib - page.component.ts**

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, HostBinding, Inject, Input, Output} from '@angular/core';
import {AbstractPageService} from '../../services/abstract-page.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'dc-page',
  templateUrl: './page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page.component.scss']
})
export class PageComponent {

  @HostBinding('class') styleClass = 'd-flex flex-column';

  @Input() customStyleClass = null;

  @Input() showLogoutButton = true;
  // @Output() logoutButtonClick: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(@Inject('PageService') protected pageService: AbstractPageService) {
  }

  logout(): void {
    this.pageService.logout();
  }
}
```

**Component Lib - abstract-page.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export abstract class AbstractPageService {

  abstract logout(): void;

}
```

---

And here the use in a project:

**Project - app.module.ts**

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {FontAwesomeModule} from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';

import {ComponentsModule} from 'components';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: AppComponent},

  // otherwise redirect to home
  {path: '**', redirectTo: ''}
];


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    FontAwesomeModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    ComponentsModule.forRoot(PageService),
  ],
  providers: [
    // {provide: 'PageService', useClass: PageService}
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**Project - page.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {AbstractPageService} from '../../../projects/components/src/lib/services/abstract-page.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PageService extends AbstractPageService {

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  logout() {
    console.log('Ausloggen!');
  }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps an `AbstractPageClass` would be a better and cleaner solution than a service.

Comment: Apparently, no one has a solution, or it's a mistake on my part.

Comment: Yes, abstraction is better solution than emitter and it is doable. I use abstraction in all my libraries.

Comment: @SunilSingh can you please give us an example

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I used this approach but ran into one problem:

**The `PageService` is not the same singleton instance in the library as in the application.** Because it is provided in multiple modules (application module and the library module), it creates a new instance for each module.

What I ended up doing was providing my service through a `string` in the application module:

```js
// app.module.ts in the root application
providers: [
  {
    provide: 'PageService',
    useClass: PageService
  }
]
```

Then injecting the service where needed using `@Inject()`

```js
// anywhere in the root application where the service is needed
constructor(@Inject('PageService') private pageService: PageService) {}
```

---

Then, in the *library*, I created a simple interface:

```js
export interface AbstractPageService {
  logout(): void;
}
```

Then, I can simply inject the service in the library through the `Inject()` decorator and type it using the interface (without the need to implement the interface in the root application):

```js
// anywhere in the library where the service is needed
constructor(@Inject('PageService') private pageService: AbstractPageService) {}
```

Now both the root application *and* the library use the same singleton instance of the `PageService`, as provided in the root application.

Comment: +1. Thanks for this answer. A tip to anyone implementing this solution: I was using the concrete service in some places in the consuming module (e.g. `PageService`) _and_ I was using the abstract service in the library module. In _both_ places I needed to manually specify the injection token to get Angular to use the same instance (e.g. use `@Inject('PageService') private pageService: PageService` in the app module).

Comment: To add on to the answer from @robertkroll - I found out that I needed to specify the injection token ONLY in the top most application wrapper within the app (apart from the library of course). I could use the cleaner `private pageService: PageService` in a child component as long as some parent/ancestor had the injection token defined. But to avoid any confusion, I will probably use the injection token everywhere.

Comment: you can inject like { provide: MinimalLoggerAbstract, useExisting: LoggerService }

https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action

Answer (score 2):

To reuse singleton

### Provide in application appModule.ts

```
{ provide: 'currentCompanyService', useFactory: getCompanyServiceFactory, deps: [AppInitService]}
```

Create factory which just returns injected instance.

```
export function getCompanyServiceFactory(appInitService: AppInitService): AppInitService {
 return appInitService;
}
```

### Inject in library component

```
public CustomLibraryComponent {

   private companyService: AppInitService;

   constructor(@Inject('currentEnvironment') environment: any,
               @Inject('currentCompanyService') companyService: AppInitService) {
       this.environment = environment;
       this.companyService = companyService;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Sunil Singh said, a normal abstract class is the solution (without `@Injectable`).

```
export abstract class AbstractPageService {

  abstract logout(): void;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there should be 'useValue' instead of 'useClass'.

```js
export class ComponentsModule {
  static forRoot(pageService): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: ComponentsModule,
      providers: [
        {provide: 'PageService', useClass: pageService}
      ]
    };
  }
}
```