# Angular 9 do abstract classes for services need the @injectable decorator?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

After upgrading to Angular 9 my abstract classes that some services extend are automatically decorated with the `@injectable` as written in the Angular 9 Migration guide.

Everything on my app works.

However I dont understand why abstract classes have to be decorated, since the concrete classes that extend them do have the `@injectable` decorator.

I also read this question [Angular library module inject service with abstract class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51859038/angular-library-module-inject-service-with-abstract-class) and there its advised to remove the `@injectable` from abstracts.

So should I remove the decorator ?

Is this just an Angular "mistake" for adding that decorator to my abstracts?

Also, I noticed that the `@directive` decorator has been added to other abstract classes that are used to implement components.

Comment: check this:https://hackmd.io/@alx/S1XKqMZeS

Comment: @Chellappan thanks that explains a lot. I think from what I read it's due to Ivy right ?

Comment: yes @Jimmy Kane

Comment: Feel free to post an answer with this content. 

I d gladly accept it :-)

Comment: At the same time this link and insight helped me solve this: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58649778/lazy-loading-after-page-reload-cannot-find-some-module-declarations/59237886#59237886

Comment: Since you already added answer to your old question, I have upvoted your answer.

Comment: yes but how about you answering this one :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Till Angular 8 decorators were optional for base classes for Directives and Components. With With latest angular version(9). classes require decorators.

[For More Details](https://hackmd.io/@alx/S1XKqMZeS)

[Link2](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/exciting-time-ahead-be-ready-for-angular-9-b3dbb4078c47)

Answer (score 1):

To add some additional information:

A key concept in Ivy is locality, so in order to compile or recompile a component the compiler no longer scans the whole code base - only the component is recompiled; and, all behavior of the component must be captured in the compiled class. [The link provided in other answers provides more details on the "why"](https://hackmd.io/@alx/S1XKqMZeS).

The "new to Ivy" requirement that base classes (abstract or not) have an Angular decorator (`@Directive`, `@Component`, `@Injectable`, `@NgModule`) only applies if the base classes use Angular features, eg if they implement lifecycle interfaces like `OnInit` or `OnDestroy`. If your base classes don't use Angular features you don't need an Angular decorator.

In Angular 9, this requirement is optional; but don't remove the decorators from your base classes that were put there by the CLI upgrade, because this requirement is non-optional in Angular 10.

Comment: Hey, Thanks Crimbo. This indeed ads quite a good context

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is related to the Undecorated Parent pattern.

I cannot comment on your code specifically without seeing it, but as a general point it may be better to **use aggregation rather than inheritance**.  In other words redesign your base class as a service, which is then injected into the derived class.

Comment: Good advice ! Thank you already doing that mostly now

Answer (score 0):

Some additional info here dealing with this:

- We know about the Ivy requirements for class decorators etc.

But, here's a sequence I just went through, which seems to imply there is no way to create an abstract base class for a directive, if that class uses angular features (Input, etc). Refactoring would be required.

- Had a base class used by a component. It's abstract and uses angular features.
- Did the upgrade, saw the empty Directive added.
- Would not compile. Meta data obj required in directive.
- Looked in docs (Angular.io), said to add the data with blank selector.

I did all that, even though TS lint cries about the blank selector, which I turned off with a tslint:disable...

...which although no longer shows as a lint error, now shows as a build error (actually says, "please add it!"). So I added a selector with some notion it will never be used, since the class is abstract.

But...

...the class was formerly not added to a module. I didn't write the original code, and was surprised this had never come up in a --prod build, but reading about the former graphic engine, I see it was forgiving as it had global visibility. But Ivy doesn't, it compiles in isolation, so you need the decorator, which I put, and the no-module error comes right up. So I added it to the relevant module.

...no profit. "Can not add abstract constructor to non abstract constructor." In other words I guess, you can't declare an abstract class in a module (at least, not the usual "just add it to declarations" way).

So ultimately, short of thinking through a refactor of a fairly complex component hierarchy, I just removed abstract from the class definition.

This sequence however, does invite the opportunity to use that base class directly and via its selector. Which is not a good state for the framework to force you into.

I fiddled around a bit but couldn't find a way straight around it.

So to extend the answer here:

"It seems you can't have abstract classes if they use angular features, because if you use those features, you must use an angular decorator on the class, which means it must be declared in a module, which forbids declaring abstract classes."

(And even though the docs say "you can leave the selector blank", unless you want to tweak your rules, it seems you can't).

Comment: I am using all the time abstracts with angular features and no declaration anywhere

Comment: If you read the docs, you can't do it anymore. Classes that use angular features must have a decorator. Are you sure you are compiling with Angular 10?

Comment: Sorry my bad on commenting. I mean I don't declare the class in the module.  >which means it must be declared in a module, which forbids declaring abstract classes. 

I suppose I was refering to local modules but you to dependencies? 

Or I am understanding totally wrong care to help ?